# What Metrics Providers can be used with ArgoCD except Prometheus?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, canary-deployment, argoproj, argocd

I'm trying to use AnalysisTemplate for Canary promotion and curious about may i use Stackdriver or Istio or Anthos as metric providers?

Only Prometheus is mentioned in Official Documentation.